# Add serial data received event handler to f# serial port reader

Tags: f#

I am having simple read write instructions in f# to communicate between serial ports:

```
        async {
            do! port.AsyncWriteLineAsByte messange            
            let! response = port.AsyncReadLineAsByte() 

            return response
        }
```

Where response is byte[] and method is simple as that:

```
    member this.AsyncReadLineAsByte() : Async<byte[]> =
        async { 

            let buffer_ref = ref (Array.zeroCreate<byte> this.ReadBufferSize)
            let buffer = !buffer_ref

            let! read_bytes = this.BaseStream.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, this.ReadBufferSize)

            return buffer
        }
```

And well it works, it sends and recives messages, there is one but in all this.
Reading responses shold be on event of some sort. I am new to F# but i tried something like:

```
    async {

        let data_recived_event = port.AsyncReadLineAsByte() 

        do! port.AsyncWriteLineAsByte messange  

        port.DataReceived.AddHandler(data_recived_event) //  it says SerialDataReciveHandler is what he expects

        let! response = ??? 

        return response
    }
```

But no luck, documentation is rather, for f# it just specify prototype and method construction not a practical usage. I need a event and a way to return that value , is there a way?

EDIT:

Ive been able to add event as serial port namespace has DataReceived.AddHandler event subscription.

So now it looks:

```
        async {

        let data_recived() =
            async{
                let! buffer = port.AsyncReadLineAsByte()
                printfn "Response from event %A" buffer
                // return buffer
            } |> fun response -> Async.RunSynchronously(response)

        port.DataReceived.AddHandler(fun _ _ -> data_recived())

        do! port.AsyncWriteLineAsByte messange  
        let! response = port.AsyncReadLineAsByte()            

        return response
    }
```

And it works, problem is still how to return such a value from event, if I do something like:

```
            let data_recived() =
                async{
                    let! buffer = port.AsyncReadLineAsByte()

                    printfn "Response from event %A" buffer
                    return buffer
                } |> fun response -> Async.RunSynchronously(response)

            port.DataReceived.AddHandler(fun _ _ -> response = data_recived())
```

Is says it expects uint and get bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on how serial ports work, but you can wait for an event inside `async` workflow using the `Async.AwaitEvent` operation. So, you could write something like this:

```
let writeAndRead () = async {
  let port = new SerialPort("COM1")
  port.Write("TEST")
  let mutable finished = false
  while not finished do
    let! e = port.DataReceived |> Async.AwaitEvent
    let data = port.ReadExisting()
    printfn "GOT: %A" data
    finished <- data.Contains("EOF") }
```

The only caveat here is that the `DataReceived` event might be triggered concurrently, while you are processing the received data in the body of the loop - and then you will miss the event. I'm not sure how serial ports work and whether this can actually happen, but it could lead to problems.

To address that, you could use the [`BlockingQueueAgent` type](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-blockingqueueagent-1.html) from F# Async Extras. This would let you implement a queue of notifications - so the `DataReceived` handler would add notifications to the queue and you would then read them from the queue in the loop. I have not actually tested this, but I think something like this should work:

```
let writeAndRead () = async {
  let queue = BlockingQueueAgent<_>(Int32.MaxValue)
  let port = new SerialPort("COM1")
  port.DataReceived.Add(fun e -> queue.Add(e))
  port.Write("TEST")
  let mutable finished = false
  while not finished do
    let! e = queue.AsyncGet()
    let data = port.ReadExisting()
    finished <- data.Contains("EOF") }
```

**EDIT:** Moved the `queue` event handler setup *before* writing any data to the port.

Comment: Both let! e = queue.AsyncGet() and let! e = port.DataReceived |> Async.AwaitEvent are just stuck and wait even if event is received

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz I did an edit and moved the `DataRecieved` handler setup _before_ the line that writes to the port. That could have been the cause why an event was missed. With the change, I think the events should all be recorded correctly - and none of them can be lost.